# Manipulate MS Excel tables Based on foreign Keys similar to SQL Inner-Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, macos, join

We are in the process of converting a SQL Server process to Postgres.  In the interim, we want to use MS Excel to manually update the tables and load to Postgres. The SQL Server process does an inner-join on two tables to match the foreign keys and initialize certain columns based on those fields.

Is there a way to simulate this process in MS Excel? I have researched some Excel functions such as `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX MATCH` but they fall a little short on getting the job done.

The SQL query is as follows:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET OrderCount = 0,   
    Cost = 0.  
FROM table1.  
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.OrderId = table1.orderID 
WHERE table2.shippingChoice = 1
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand the question (excel to postgres), but what part of the Excel formulas don't work? Perhaps you need to wrap IF or IFERROR around them, depending what you want to do.

Comment: Depends on what year of Excel you have.  If you have Excel with PowerPivot you can load up both data models and then set your relationships.

Comment: Power Pivot is not available for the Mac.  And Power query is only available on Office Insider.

Comment: @Isolated I jus need to create the proper CSV files in MS with the changes and then export to Postgres.

Comment: Do you have MS Access on your Mac, Office Suite?

Comment: You could do something like this. Pretend Columns A:C are table1 while Columns G:H are table2. Column_D is the new updated_OrderCount, with a formula: `=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,$G$1:$H$8,2) = 1,0,B2)`. So it will set the Updated_OrderCount to 0 if the shipping choice is 1. Else, it will use the current OrderCount. You cannot change data with formulas, but you can create other columns. If you want to change the data, then you'll need VBA.

Comment: @Isolated , Thanks for the reply, but, doesn't this assume that the rows are in the same order for each table?

Comment: Sort does not matter if Table2 is distinct. That is, each orderId can have just one shipping choice. We can help if you provide some sample data.

Comment: *We want to use MS Excel to manually update the tables* ... Why not MS Access where you can link both tables from either MSSQL or Postgres via ODBC drivers or keep exact SQL and run it in a pass-through query.

Comment: @Isolate, I updated with example spreadsheet

Comment: @Vlookip we do not have MS Access in the enterprise.  Yeah.  I could have just imported the tables to access and run the queries my self.  :). I thought of that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Table2 is distinct, then I think the following would work. But you'll want to check and confirm.

In picture below, I'm adding Column D and E as new columns.

Cell D3 formula:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A3,$G$3:$H$9,2) = 1,0,B3)
```

Drag is across and down, and you're done. If the shipping choice is 1, then use 0's, otherwise use the values.

[image]

Comment: Just one question:  Just to make sure that I am following your example correctly:  

1. VLOOKUP is looking for the value in $A3, within the range (box) $G2:$H9
($G2 includes the header. Is this a typo)?
2. If it finds the value, it returns '2' in $B3.
3. The wrapper IF condition looks at the VLOOKUP result =1 then use '0' or the value in B3.

Why is the range G2:H9 and not H3:H9?

Comment: Should be G3:H9. Sorry, I added a row at some point. DOesn't really matter, as you could use the entire column (G:H) in tihs case. The "2" is the column it's looking up in that array. So if the 2nd column in array G3:H9 is a 1 (ie, the shipping choice is 1) then say 0, else say the amount from cell B3.